# Securely accessing login data in two different Activities in Android

Tags: java, android, security

My application requires the user to login on their first visit, and then it stores this in SharedPreferences for any future times the application is launched.

I'm trying to implement a sign out feature, and I'm wondering what the best way would be.

As of right now, my LoginActivity and SignOutActivity are separate since they occur on different screens.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to store the preferences in a way that both of these activities can access the login data and have it still be secure.  How would all of you suggest I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either just use the [default SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) or get the SharedPreferences with the same name in both activities; the whole point of them is that they're shared :) I'm a little worried that you think `SharedPreferences` are actually secure or isolated; they're not. Anyone with root permission [can read them](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg22945.html) (although other apps without root permission can't by default). If you're storing passwords or anything like that, encrypt them.

There are 3 [modes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for SharedPreferences: `MODE_PRIVATE`, `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. `MODE_PRIVATE`, the default and the most restrictive one, still allows free access to the Preferences to any activity in your own app (or any other app you create with the same [user ID](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid)).

Comment: Ahh, ok.  After reading the documentation, I convinced myself that they were tied to an Activity, but I hadn't tried specifying a name and attempting to access them that way.  As for security, is there a more secure way to store the passwords?  Right now, I'm using an MD5 hash.

Comment: pretty sure md5 has been proven to not be so secure anymore, use sha1

Comment: Actually, sha1 has also been proven to "not be so secure" too -- use at least sha2 (256/512). If it's just a password for local use, I'd SHA512 the password after salting it. Of course, unless the data in your app they're entering the password to get to is also encrypted, anyone with root can get to that too; you'll still need to use an encryption strategy of some sort for any of the actual data in your app that warrants password protecting.